# Green ring on resources

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm in TH8 farming and I notice that several players have these weird green rings on their resources. I'm not sure what these are or what they do.

Can anyone explain this?

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are boost rings. You can pay gems to have resources generate at double speed. Right now, there is a special offer going on where you can pay one Gem and get a 24 hour boost.

Comment: It will produce double the amount of actual.

Comment: Added @Naveen-நவீன்

Comment: The part about the "right now, there's a special offer..." isn't going to be relevant for very long, and there's no mention about boosting other buildings. This answer could definitely use a lot of improving.

Answer (score 4):

The rings you see around the resource collectors are boosts. You can pay 5 gems, to double the production of one collector for 24 hours. (The capacity of your collector, or the loot available to raid from the collector, doesn't change, however).

This is true not only for resource collectors. You can boost barracks (to speed training by x4), spell factory, and heroes (to reduce their regeneration time).

However, if you decide to boost, remember that more loot will attract people to attack your base, which may end up with you losing a lot of loot (keep collecting regularly and avoid piling them in the collectors).

On occasions, Supercell discounts the cost of boosting resource collectors and/or other buildings down to 1 gem each for a limited time.